# Can I commit a large file with bazaar, or is there a better approach to versioning a database dump?

Tags: python, database, memory, version-control, bazaar

Bazaar limits the file size that it can commit based on the available virtual memory (according to an [open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/109114)).

I would like to put a database (as mysqldump text file) under version control. The database is 3 GB and I am working on a server with 64GB of memory. I do not understand why this would be a problem. When I attempt to commit, I get the error reported in the bug:

> bzr: ERROR: exceptions.OverflowError: requested number of bytes is more than a Python string can hold

Is there a way that I can get this file under bazaar version control?

My preference for bazaar is that I am familiar with it, but I plan to automate the dump and check in as a cron job so any suitable version control system will do.

---

Two options I have come up with so far, until a better solution appears. Currently, I keep a copy of each weekly dump backup, storage is not an issue at this point. Otherwise, I could keep the first dump, diff the original and new version of the dump, and version control that. This would keep a record of the changes, but it would not be possible to return to an earlier state. I am not comfortable with this unless there would  be a straightforward way to revert.

```
mysqldump mydb > mydb_base.sql
touch mydb_diff
bzr add mydb_diff
bzr commit -m 'first commit'
```

then in the cron script

```
mysqldump mydb > mydb.sql
diff mydb_base.sql mydb.sql > mydb_diff
bzr commit -m "`date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M` mydb diff" mydb_diff
```

Comment: Do you accept "natural" versioning suggestions, but not bzr'ed?

Comment: Also, FYI - [Bug 839210 "Bazaar crashes when adding a files larger than 4GB"](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2011-September/025196.html) is fresh

Comment: @lazybadger ill take any suggestiins

Comment: You really, really, really shouldn't be putting a file of this size into version control.

Comment: @TobyAllen why not? How else would you recommend that I version a database?

Comment: BY doing backup with the right tool as Cobian Backup for example.

Comment: @TridenT I can't find any documentation for Cobian Backup, could you give a simple explanation of what makes it the right tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I love Bazaar, I would not recommend that you use it for this purpose, unless you definitely need to keep every version of your data indefinitely. If in stead you only need a fixed number of past versions (e.g. 10) or only for a fixed period (eg. 2 years), then I'd suggest that you use an incremental backup tool like [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/).

Comment: thanks. that sounds like a better tool for the job, I think keeping backups from a series like 1 day, 1 week, 1 month, 1 year, would work, e.g., I can get rid of old versions as I go along.

Comment: It looks like that feature is not available yet :( http://wiki.rdiff-backup.org/wiki/index.php/DeleteIntermediate

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in bzr, fixed in recent versions. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/683191

Comment: I am not sure if this is the same bug, https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/109114 remains open

Comment: That's a different bug - and it should not be relevant if there is 32Gb RAM and database dumps of 3Gb.

Answer (score 0):

If "Foreign VCS" suggestions are applicable, I have to say

- [Mercurial 2.0](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WhatsNew#Mercurial_2.0_.282011-11-01.29) with [LargeFiles extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LargefilesExtension)

Comment: My understanding is that largefile stores the full version of each file. Also, does Mercurial 2.0 actually support files larger than 2Gb in its dirstate file yet?

Comment: stores the full version of each file, yes, but only in one location and not inside repo - "Files added as largefiles are not tracked directly by Mercurial; rather, their revisions are identified by a checksum, and Mercurial tracks these checksums... A largefiles store, typically on a centralized server, has every past revision of every largefile. The local repository has a largefile store in '.hg/largefiles' which holds a subset of the largefiles needed." Yes, current limit is 2G - "Unfortunately, the use of dirstate limits largefiles to 2 GB. "

Answer (score -2):

First, you want to b**ackup things** with bazaar more than using a versionning system. That's different !
Bazaar stores changeset  - differences between files - and keep tracker of them and their merge.
Even if I can understand your point, **I think your are not using the right tool**.

Anyway, to answer your question, **a simple workaround is to reduce the file size**. As a mysqldump is a text file, its size can be dramatically reduced by compressing it.

So **a possible workaround is to compress it** with 7zip (or whatever you want) before sending it to bazaar.

This way prevents you from doing real merge or diff from bazaar, but I understand that it is not your priority.

Comment: Compressing it usually isn't a a good idea, since that will actually make it harder for bzr to generate a delta against the previous version of the file. Bazaar will store the files in a compressed manner anyway.

Comment: I know that it is not a good idea, as I mentioned, but it is better than not working at all !

Comment: Fair enough, it's a workaround for bug 683191 (though that's also fixed now). It'll lead to more disk usage though.